# Output is not printed in console in eclipse while running but is printed in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, jsch

I am trying out to login to remote server using `jsch` and execute a script which echos `Hello World`. The output of this file is not printed to console when run java code directly but is printed when I step through in debug mode. My code looks like this:

```
1    import java.io.BufferedReader;
2    import java.io.IOException;
3    import java.io.InputStream;
4    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
5    import java.util.List;
6    
7    import org.slf4j.Logger;
8    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
9    
10    import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
11    import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
12    import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
13    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
14    import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
15    
16    public class SSHUtility {
17      
18      public static void main(String[] args) {
19          executeScript("user", "password", "127.0.0.1", 22, "/opt/helloworld.sh");
20          println "done"
21      }
22      
23      public static void executeScript(String pUser, String pPassword, String pServer, int pPort, String pCommand) {
24          System.out.println("Executing on ssh");
25          try {
26              JSch lJSCH = new JSch();
27              Session lSession = lJSCH.getSession(pUser, pServer, pPort);
28              lSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
29              lSession.setPassword(pPassword);
30              lSession.connect();
31    
32              ChannelExec lChannelExec = (ChannelExec)lSession.openChannel("exec");
33    
34              lChannelExec.setCommand(pCommand);
35              lChannelExec.setInputStream(null);
36              InputStream stdout = lChannelExec.getInputStream();
37              InputStream stderr = lChannelExec.getErrStream();
38              lChannelExec.connect();
39              
40              waitForChannelClosed(lChannelExec);
41    
42              int lExitStatus = lChannelExec.getExitStatus();
43              
44              BufferedReader brStdOut = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
45              BufferedReader brStdErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
46              
47              int brValue = 0;
48              while((brValue=brStdOut.read()) != -1)
49              {
50                  char brChar = (char)brValue;
51                  System.out.print(brChar);    /***This is printed only in debug mode ***/
52              }
53              
54              while((brValue=brStdErr.read()) != -1)
55              {
56                  char brChar = (char)brValue;
57                  System.out.print(brChar);    /***This is printed only in debug mode ***/
58              }           
59              
60              if(lExitStatus < 0) {
61                  LOGGER.info("Done, but exit status not set!");
62              }
63              else if(lExitStatus > 0) {              
64                  LOGGER.info("Done, but with error, exitStatus : " + lExitStatus);
65              }
66              else {
67                  LOGGER.info("Script successfully executed : " + pCommand);
68              }
69              
70              lChannelExec.disconnect();          
71              lSession.disconnect();
72    
73          }
74          catch(Exception e) {
75              LOGGER.info("Error executing script : " + pCommand);
76          }
77      }
78              
79      private static void waitForChannelClosed(ChannelExec pChannel) throws IOException
80      {
81          InputStream lStdOut = pChannel.getInputStream();
82          byte[] buffer = null;
83          while(true)
84          {
85              while(lStdOut.available() > 0)
86              {
87                  int i = lStdOut.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
88                  if (i < 0) { break; }
89                  System.out.print(new String(buffer, 0, i));//print response to console
90              }
91    
92              if (pChannel.isClosed()) {//It is never closed 
93                  System.out.println("exit-status: " + pChannel.getExitStatus());
94                  break;
95              }
96              try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
97          }   
98      }
99    }
```

Specifically output of line 51 and 57 appear only in debug mode. But when I run program it does not appear in console. Why is such weird behavior?

Comment: slf4j has 5 levels.
you must have set your logging level to debug. That simply means all logs below debug level will not be printed.
check your logback.xml or post it here

Comment: am not talking about `LOGGER` output. Its line 51 and 57. Question modified for more clearity.

Comment: Is `System.out.print` ever called? = Is `brStdOut.read()` ever `!= 1`? I guess not. But you should tell us.

Comment: when I step through, yes it enters inside those `while` loops and prints output of `System.out.print` to console. However when run, I do not get any such output in the console.

Comment: That does not answer my question. What if you put `System.out.print("before")` before the `while` and `System.out.print("inside")` inside the `while` and `System.out.print("after")` after the `while`?

Comment: yes in run mode it does  not show those `before,inside,after` stuff in console, in debug mode it does: https://gist.github.com/Mahesha999/b579ef87b2c3d770e7a37523e425ce2e

Comment: at the bottom of the above gist I have pasted the output directly from eclipse console in both debug and run mode